# Laravel array validation with custom rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

In `CustomFormRequest` i have something like this:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'events' => ['array'],
        'events.*.type' => ['required'],
        'events.*.data' => [app(SomeRule::class)],
    ];
}
```

`SomeRule`:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value): bool
{
    var_dump($attribute);//events.0.data
    var_dump($value);exit;
}
```

In `SomeRule::passes` i need to have access to `events.X.type` (so for `events.5.data` i need `events.5.type`). Any ideas?

Comment: Use helper function `request()` to get your data

Comment: hmm... but i need to get index from `events.0.data`. Is better way to do that than `explode`?

Comment: maybe review your validation to do `'events.*' => [app(SomeRule::class)],` and then `$value` should have both type and data (maybe, I don't know if it will work)

Comment: @apokryfos I think this would be the most clean solution..

Answer (score 2):

As a user commented in my question [Validating array in Laravel using custom rule with additional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963713/validating-array-in-laravel-using-custom-rule-with-additional-parameter/54964424#54964424), you can do it with this code, in your case it would be something like

```
class SomeRule implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $index = explode('.', $attribute)[1];
        $type = request()->input("events.{$index}.type");

        return someConditional ? true : false;
    }
}
```